# How to get Department Name, Manager, Role title using System.DirectoryServices in Windows Form

Tags: c#

Am newbie to C# script development, am trying to fetch Department Name, Manager Name & Role Title in windows form labels thru adding reference system.directoryservices. Can anyone support me, how to get the details in form labels.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check the tutorial on how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how the manager is stored, but you can debug below method and look on the results and figure out what you are looking for.

The below example, demonstrate how to access user info:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    //from nuget you need this 2
    using System.DirectoryServices;
    using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetUserAD();
        }

        public void GetUserAD()
        {

            var userDto = new UserDto();

            using PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, Environment.UserName);


            userDto.FirstName = up.GivenName;
            userDto.LastName = up.Surname;
            userDto.UserEmail = up.EmailAddress;
            userDto.LastLogon = up.LastLogon;
            userDto.FixPhone = up.VoiceTelephoneNumber;
            userDto.UserDisplayName = up.DisplayName;
            userDto.JobTitle = up.Description;

            DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = up.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            userDto.Department = directoryEntry.Properties["department"]?.Value as string;
            userDto.MobilePhone = directoryEntry.Properties["mobile"]?.Value as string;
            userDto.MemberOf = directoryEntry.Properties["memberof"]?.OfType<string>()?.ToList();
        }
    }
    public class UserDto
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public string LastLogon { get; set; }
        public string FixPhone { get; set; }
        public string UserDisplayName { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
        public List<string> MemberOf { get; set; }
    }
}
```